# Is it normal that uploading is higher than downloading? (traffic network)

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, network

[image]

**Config**:
Windows 10, i5, RAM : 16Go

**Bitcoin options** : Version : 24.0.1
with Serveur RPC on, UPnP on, natpmp on, no proxy, no onion

Does it seems normal to you ?

Comment: When relaying transactions and blocks without synchronizing the entire bitcoin blockchain, it is typical to see higher sent traffic compared to received traffic. Just checked my node: in last 25 days since last reboot it gets total traffic 1.03 TB (↑ 1.01 TB sent | ↓ 13.03 GB received).

Comment: The amount of incoming and outgoing connections can also impact the traffic flowing to and from your node. A node that does not keep its port (typically 8333) open, meaning that it does not allow peer nodes to connect from outside, will typically experience a minimum of outgoing traffic.

Comment: Yes, it seems ok but I still do not know the difference between my two GUIs (laptop and personal computer) : laptop GUI almost always stay below receiving traffic (same parameters) when the one you can see on the pic is still higher (sending traffic is almost egual to receiving traffic x4). Also, the GUI used on my laptop doesn't exceed peer 200 when the one on the pic can go... the current last outgoing connexion peer is around 5000 at the moment (cf start on pic). Someone understood why some GUIs go without any peer limit when seems to have limits ?

Answer (score 0):

After the IBD (Initial Block Download) when the node tries to download the whole blockchain, which is around 500GB, the node does relaying transactions and blocks to all its peers. So it's completely normal that uploading be much higher than downloading. Because when your node receives a block or transaction from one peer, it downloads `x` bytes, then it will announce it to `n` peers. So it will upload `x * n`.

I know the real scenario is much more complex than what is illustrated. But the concept is the same.

Comment: Not sure it is about downloading since the blockchain is already fully downloaded.